# Why this "printKthToLast" recursion (java) starts from end to beginning?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am studying algorithms and I am still tackling this doubt for some time.
I understand the concept behind recursions, but what I don't get is why this code below starts counting from end to begin of the Linked List:

```
public static int printKthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int index = printKthToLast(head.next, k) + 1;
    if (index == k) {
        System.out.println(k + "th to last node is " + head.data);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Look: if I want to find out the 2nd to the last item, and my linked list is {10,20,30,40}, the answer is 30. But if index is added every iteration, the index would be (2) and then the result is 20.

I understand that the code is (some how) starting from end, and this makes sense, because the second item from the end is 30. But I do not see where I tell "start from the end". It is something on the recursion I didn't get yet.

Comment: When is the first element printed? After `printKthToLast` for the second element has finished. When is the second element then printed? After `printKthToLast` for the third element has finished, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach a statement, it has to be evaluated completely before the program can continue to the next one.

For methods, that means they need to be entered and returned from by reaching the end of the method, a `return` statement or raising an exception. Only then a statement that consists of a method call is considered "evaluated".

Now, in your case you have this:

```
int index = printKthToLast(head.next, k) + 1;
if (index == k) {
    System.out.println(k + "th to last node is " + head.data);
}
```

First comes `printKthToLast(head.next, k) + 1;` and only after that you print  your result. That means in order to reach the printing statement, the statement before has to be evaluated completely, which will start the recursive chain.

So the flow is something like this:

```
printKthToLast(head.next, k)
|   printKthToLast(head.next.next, k)
|   |   printKthToLast(head.next.next.next, k)
|   |   |   ......
|   |   |   printKthToLast(head...next, k)
|   |   |   System.out.println(head...data) // innermost method, prints the last element
|   |   |   return index
|   |   |   ......
|   |   System.out.println(head.next.next.data)
|   |   return index
|   System.out.println(head.next.data)
|   return index
System.out.println(head.data)
return index
```

As you can see the last element is printed first, then the innermost method is actually finished and returns to the previous method and so on, until you've reached the "outermost" method.

Comment: This is what I was searching. Now I understand that the recursion is "one inside an other" (nested, like Inception movie :D ). This is the point I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the given recursive code:

1. The recursion traverses to the end of the linked list.
2. As recursion returns from the end to the beginning, it increments an
   "index" counting nodes from the tail.
3. When "index" equals "k", it prints the node's value, which is the
   kth node from the end.

Your confusion is because while recursion goes deep to the end, as it returns, it's essentially counting backwards from the tail to the head of the list.

Comment: So it iterates all over the items before testing "if index == k"?